# Why scrollbar of JtextArea doesn't navigate?

Tags: jscrollpane, jtextarea

I use one JTextArea and JScrollBar. It has this problem when I run it and it will fill by text, I can't navigate it. i.e. when I click on arrowkey on scrolbar, nothing happen. although I write the update code for it (by using API), but it doesn't work well. What shall i do? Thanks in advance.
**I show my code as bellow:**

```
JTextArea  Result_field = new JTextArea(5,10);
    Result_field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 10));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( Result_field );

    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);


    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)Result_field.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStreamm(Result_field));
    System.setOut(printStream);

    MainPanel.add(scrollPane,gbc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem, although we define one JTextArea or ... by the size, But after that we should determine the prefer size again.